# How Can I Use XMLDocument.SelectNodes in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, xmldocument

I am a beginner in programming UWP applications, but I know c#. My question is, how could I use selectnodes in a UWP applications since the definition doesn't exist... How would i work around this issue? Thanks.

Here is my code if needed

```
XmlDocument responseXML = new XmlDocument();
responseXML.LoadXml(response);

string innerText = responseXML.SelectNodes("//maininfo").Item(0).InnerText;
responseXML.LoadXml(innerText);

info1 = responseXML.GetElementsByTagName("upnp:info1").Item(0).InnerText;
info2 = responseXML.GetElementsByTagName("upnp:info2").Item(0).InnerText;
info3 = responseXML.GetElementsByTagName("dc:info3").Item(0).InnerText;
info4 = responseXML.GetElementsByTagName("dc:info4").Item(0).InnerText;
```

Comment: indentation was off .. made the question more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could I use selectnodes in a UWP applications since the definition doesn't exist... How would i work around this issue?

The problem is that you have used wrong namespace(`System.Xml`) for `XmlDocument`. Please use `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom` namespace. For more you could refer to [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument) class official documentation.

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;

......

XmlDocument responseXML = new XmlDocument();
responseXML.LoadXml(response);
string innerText = responseXML.SelectNodes("//maininfo").Item(0).InnerText;
```

Here is [official XML DOM sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument), please check.