# Visual Studio won't compile due to missing XML-definition

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2017

I made a project in VS2017 that reads a XML-file (among other things). It has been compiling without problems... but suddenly, the compiler displays numerous errors, regarding XML:

> Error CS1061  'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for
>   'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm not missing anything, I believe. Here are some selected lines from the code. SelectedNodes has a red, squiggly line beneath it.

```
using System.Xml;
...
...
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.LoadXml(s);
medias = xDocument.SelectNodes("server/media/*");
```

The references are pretty standard.

[image]

The problems started, the moment I began installing some nuget packages (Emgu) and I have made minor modifications, like the target version... but nothing else. I tried copying the code to a new project, but same same.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

For UWP, you need to use different namespace since it is not available in System.Xml namespace: [System.Xml namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185484.aspx)

Use the following namespace instead: 
`using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;`

RE [How Can I Use XMLDocument.SelectNodes in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681575/how-can-i-use-xmldocument-selectnodes-in-uwp)